# Set transparency of pixel by it's value in cv::Mat

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have two `cv::Mat` objects, one is `CV_8UC1` and it's loaded from grayscale `QImage`:

```
QImage tmp = QImage(path/to/image);
setMap(cv::Mat(tmp.height(),
               tmp.width(),
               CV_8UC1,
               const_cast<uchar *>(tmp.bits()),
               static_cast<size_t>(tmp.bytesPerLine())
               ));
```

After I load it, I want to get every pixel value and change transparency of that pixel by its value and convert it to `QImage`. Currently, I access pixels like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < getMap().rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < getMap().cols; j++){
        uchar v = getMap().at<uchar>(i,j);
        //qDebug() << v;
    }
}
```

Now, I think I have only one choice - convert it to `CV_8UC4` (or copy it somehow) and change it's alpha value, but I don't know how to copy/convert it by pixel. As I said, I need to change it's transparency by it's grayscale value.

I tried this, but when I did, program crashed

```
getMap().convertTo(requestedMap_, CV_8UC4);

for(int i = 0; i < getMap().rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < getMap().cols; j++){
        uchar v = getMap().at<uchar>(i,j);
        if(v < 50)
            requestedMap_.at<cv::Vec4i>(i,j)[3] = 0;
    }
}
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the threshold value of gray-scale pixel, which qualifies to be replace with a transparent pixel.

Comment: @ZdaR For now it's constant, I'll change it later, but in showed code it's  "if(v < 50)"

Comment: Use `cv::cvtColor(getMap(),requestedMap_,cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);`.

Comment: @zindarod Thank you, now it works, but I need to apply color map after that process, and it's not compatibile with that color.

Comment: opencv hast a lookup table function (LUT) . I'm not sure whether it can handle 4 channel matrices, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Ok, that worked, thank you